# Ошибка при проверке в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пишу консольное приложение для товарища, изменяющее файл hosts. Возникли некоторые проблемы

```
import time
import os
class path_set:
    def __bool__(self):
        return False
password_set = False
def set_password():
    password_set = True
    print ("Введите пароль: ")
    password = input()
    print ("Пароль: {0}. Сохранить (y, n)?".format(password))
    key = input()
    while True:
        if (key == 'y') or (key == 'Y'):
            break
        elif (key == 'n') or (key == 'N'):
            print ("Введите пароль снова")
            password = input()
        else:
            print('Вы ввели неправильный ответ! Введите опять')
            key = input()
    return password
def dialog():
    print("Вы хотите добавить(1) или удалить(2) строку в hosts?")
    answer = input()
    while True:
        if answer == '1':
            if path_set == False:
                print ("Введите ТОЧНЫЙ путь до фала hosts")
                directory = input()
                path_set = True
                print ('\n')
                hosts = open(directory, w)
                print ("Введите ТОЛЬКО адрес сайта")
                line_adress = input()
                line = '127.0.0.1\t' + line_adress
                hosts.write(line)
                hosts.close
            else:
                if path_set == False:
                    print ("Введите ТОЧНЫЙ путь до фала hosts")
                    directory = input()
                    path_set = True
                    print ('\n')
                    hosts = open(directory, w)
                    print ("Введите ТОЛЬКО адрес сайта")
                    line_adress = input()
                    line = '127.0.0.1\t' + line_adress
                    hosts.write(line)
                    hosts.close
                else:
                    hosts = open(directory, w)
                    print ("Введите ТОЛЬКО адрес сайта")
                    line_adress = input()
                    line = '127.0.0.1\t' + line_adress
                    hosts.write(line)
                    hosts.close
            break
        elif answer == '2':
            print ("Введите пароль")
            password_check = input()
            if password_check == password:
                hosts = open(directory, "r+")
                print (hosts.readlines(), "\n\n\n")
                print ("Введите ТОЛЬКО адрес сайта, которых хотите удалить")
                line_delete = input()
                d = hosts.readlines()
                hosts.seek(0)
                for i in d:
                    if i != ('127.0.0.1\t' + line_delete):
                        hosts.write(i)
                hosts.truncate()
                hosts.close
                break
            else:
                print ("Пароль неверен\n")
        else:
            print("Вы ввели неправильный ответ! Введите опять")
            answer = input()

if password_set == False:
    password = set_password()
    dialog()
else:
    dialog()
```

И тут возникли проблемы, одна проблема. Собственно, текст ошибки

```
  File "Путь\до\моего\файла.py", line 29, in dialog
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'path_set' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот не понятна эта конструкция:

```
class path_set:
    def __bool__(self):
        return False
```

Это создание типа, а не экземпляр. Сделайте проще:

```
path_set = False
```

Comment: Это проблему использования до присваивания не исправит.

Comment: Исправит, если напишите это в правильном месте кода

Answer (score 0):

Если не переписывать всю логику с ноля, рабочий когда который прогнал у себя, имеет исправление в этом месте

```
def dialog():
    print("Вы хотите добавить(1) или удалить(2) строку в hosts?")
    answer = input()
    path_set = False
```

Переменная `path_set` у вас не определена, когда доходит дело до ее сравнения во втором `if` о чем сообщение об ошибке и говорит.

Как указал @eri нужно определить переменную до того, как она попадает в `while` цикл.